# Trying to save a struct into a file

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data {

    char *first;
    char *last;
    char *email;
    int age;
    struct data *next;
};

typedef struct data dat;
dat family;
dat family_array[4];
char array[100];

void menu(){
    printf("\n1. Father\n");
    printf("2. Mpther\n");
    printf("3. Son 1\n");
    printf("4. Son 2\n");

}

int mode_select(){
    int x;
    printf("\nMake your choice:");
    scanf("%d" ,&x);
    return x;
}
```

Opens file and returns its address

```
FILE* load_read(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Family Data.dat" , "rb");
    return fp;
}


FILE* write(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("Family Data.dat" , "wb");
    return fp;
}
```

Reads data for struct

```
dat new_data( const char *first , const char *last , const char *email , int age){
    printf("\nGive first name: ");
    scanf("%s" , array );
    first=(char*)malloc((strlen(array)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy( &(family.first), array);
    printf("\nGive last name: ");
    scanf("%s" , array);
    last=(char*)malloc((strlen(array)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&(family.last), array);
    printf("\nGive email address: ");
    scanf("%s" , array);
    email=(char*)malloc((strlen(array)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(&(family.email) , array);
    printf("\nGive age: ");
    scanf("%d" , &(family.age));
    return family;
}
```

Saves data from struct to file

```
void save_to_file(FILE *fp , dat x){
    fprintf(fp , "Dataaa:\n ");
    fprintf(fp ,"Name: %s %s\n" , x.first , x.last);
    fprintf(fp , "Email: %s\n" , x.email);
    fprintf(fp , "Age: %d\n" , x.age);

}
```

Saves data to an array

```
void save(x){
        family_array[x-1]=new_data(family.first , family.last , family.email , family.age);
}
```

Main fuction

```
int main(){
        int x ,i;
        FILE *fp;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        mode();
        x=mode_select();
        fp=write();
        save(x);
        save_to_file(fp , family_array[i]);
       }
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
```

The programm crashes when its time to save data to file with save_to_file fuction!
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Don't name your function `write()`. That's the Linux low-level function for writing to files. But I don't think it's causing your problem, stdio is supposed to be safe from this name conflict.

Comment: have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through the program?

Comment: Have you tried running the program in a debugger, and looking at the values of the variables in the `save_to_file` function?

Comment: any idea why my programm crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Your `family.first`, `family.last` and `family.email` pointer are never initialized, but you write to them using strcpy in `new_data`

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the arguments of `new_data`, and why you never use their value but replace it by a newly allocated buffer, which you never write to and never free

Comment: You beat me to it, galinette. I think the mallocs in new_data are supposed to allocate memory for these. I would probably pass in a pointer to the data struct instead of using const pointers to the contents.

Answer (score 0):

The `new_data` function is an unreadable mess, as well as being wrong.  It already returns all the information that it reads via its return value, so it does not need any parameters.

The right way is:

```
dat new_data(void)
{
    dat item = { 0 };
    char array[100];     // does not need to be global

    printf("Give first name: ");
    if ( 1 != scanf("%99s", array ) )
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    item.first = malloc( strlen(array) + 1 );
    strcpy(item.first, array);

// same for other items....

    return item;
}
```

and the code in `save` would be:

```
family_array[x-1] = new_data();
```

Your object `family` is not required either.

If you want to make `new_data()` be able to recover from errors by doing something other than `exit` then you will need to return a success/failure indication. (and include extra code for freeing memory).

Note that the POSIX functions `strdup` and/or `getline` would make this code a bit simpler.

Comment: By debbuging the programm shows me that everything is ok until the point save_to_file() opens! I tried to open file inside the fuction but nothing changed..any idea about this?                                                                         `void save_to_file(FILE *fp , dat x){
    fprintf(fp , "Dataaa:\n ");
    fprintf(fp ,"Name: %s %s\n" , x.first , x.last);
    fprintf(fp , "Email: %s\n" , x.email);
    fprintf(fp , "Age: %d\n" , x.age);

}`

Comment: The debugger will tell you what the problem was. check that fp, x.first, x.last, etc. are not null when you are saving

Comment: @KonstantinosTsirakos you should also validate that `x` is actually in the range `1` to `4` otherwise `family_array[x-1]` is an out of bounds access